# Problem with beautifulsoup.find() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to make a web crawler of [this website](https://porikochan.com/%E4%B8%80/).

I want to grab the main content in `<div class="entry-content">` so I tried this code:

```
main_content = soup.find_all("div", class_="entry-content")
```

but it always cut off at the middle of the Jukugo table.

However when I inspect the page and copy the `<div class="entry-content">` and paste it out to another file, the whole thing was displaying just fine, no cut off.

Could you help me identify what is the problem here? How should I go about crawling this site?
Thank you so much.

Sorry if my question is roundabout, English is not my native language.

What I wanted to crawl:

[image: Main content]

What I crawled:

[image: Cut off]

Comment: Maybe the rest of the table is added by JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the part I'm trying to scrape doesn't have javascript in its table.

Comment: I actually tried preloading the website and I got all of the contents! So I guess there is javascript in the page after all. Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried scraping the page using the `select` function of BeautifulSoup and think this gives your desired result:

`soup.select("div.entry-content")`.

Note that with the `select` function you can use CSS selectors (e.g., `div.entry-content`) to easily reach nested elements.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, but the table got cut off halfway just like my code.

Comment: Why do you think `select` would return anything different from `find_all`?